# Защита от декомпиляции Nuitka?

Tags: python, nuitka, декомпиляция

Может ли *python*-пакет **Nuitka** гарантировать защиту от декомпилиции и просмотра исходников? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Против декомпиляции и просмотра исходников - да. От реверс инжениринга и взлома вашей программы - нет.

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо!